# 32-Bit Hash Function for C# Objects

Tags: c#, hash, gethashcode

I wish to override object's GetHashCode() method in all my classes.  This method returns a Int32.  All the cryptographic hash functions I know of return values that will not fit in a 32-bit integer.  I want to avoid collisions as best as possible.  Should I truncate a secure hash like SHA-whatever, or use a 32-bit hash?  If using a 32-bit hash, what would be the best 32-bit hash to use?

Comment: Why do you want to override `GetHashCode`? Unless you have a really good reason to do so and you understand all of the ramifications, don't.

Comment: Hashing for security and hashing for quick identity checking are two very different problems.  For an identity hash, you don't care whether it's easy to derive new instances that produce the same hash; all you care is that it's reasonably well distributed over typical samples you use and that it be quick to compute.

Comment: You do not want a cryptographic hash, you want a fast, well-distributed hash.  Cryptographic hashes are often designed to be as slow as possible, and may not necessarily be well-distributed.  As Daniel says, don't do this unless you fully understand what you're doing.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2009/08/27/hash-functions-in-net-right-tool-for-the-right-job.aspx

Comment: You probably want to create another method, not really to override GetHashCode, since you are going to use it for a completely different purpose than GetHashCode is designed for.

Comment: I override Equals(Object obj) in all of my classes, and I want to override GetHashCode() because it throws warning for all of them.  If you override Equals(), the compiler wants you to override GetHashCode() as well, and I would like to do that correctly.

Comment: Read and understand my article on this subject before you write any code: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx

Comment: @CharlesPerniciaroIII This is generally accomplished by some operation over the values from `GetHashCode()` on the members of the class.  Can you post some code with the class members and their types?

Comment: For a graph of the expected incidence of 32 bit hash collisions if the hash is distributed randomly over the 32 bit space, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/22/socks-birthdays-and-hash-collisions.aspx

Answer (score 8):

Just a bit of information to all.  The GetHashCode() across different .NET platforms differ.  For example:  "Hello".GetHashCode() in .NET 2.0 vs. "Hello".GetHashCode() in .NET 4.0 yield different results. Hence, why you can't serialize HashTables or Dictionaries out of the box using .NET.

Implementing your own hash algos provide consistancy across platforms. Just to let you know, you don't want to go less than Int32.  My advice is to stick with Int64 (long). This way you have less collisions, which is the goal of hashing :)  This is a library that I wrote years back. Each Hash algo have their pluses and minus (speed vs. least collision). This particular version uses Strings as an Input but you can modify it as you see fit:

```
static public class StringHash
    {
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        static public Int64 RSHash(String str)
        {
            const Int32 b = 378551;
            Int32 a = 63689;
            Int64 hash = 0;

            for (Int32 i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                hash = hash * a + str[i];
                a = a * b;
            }

            return hash;
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        static public Int64 JSHash(String str)
        {
            Int64 hash = 1315423911;

            for (Int32 i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                hash ^= ((hash << 5) + str[i] + (hash >> 2));
            }

            return hash;
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        static public Int64 ELFHash(String str)
        {
            Int64 hash = 0;
            Int64 x = 0;

            for (Int32 i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                hash = (hash << 4) + str[i];

                if ((x = hash & 0xF0000000L) != 0)
                {
                    hash ^= (x >> 24);
                }
                hash &= ~x;
            }

            return hash;
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        static public Int64 BKDRHash(String str)
        {
            const Int64 seed = 131; // 31 131 1313 13131 131313 etc..
            Int64 hash = 0;

            for (Int32 i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                hash = (hash * seed) + str[i];
            }

            return hash;
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        static public Int64 SDBMHash(String str)
        {
            Int64 hash = 0;

            for (Int32 i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                hash = str[i] + (hash << 6) + (hash << 16) - hash;
            }

            return hash;
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        static public Int64 DJBHash(String str)
        {
            Int64 hash = 5381;

            for (Int32 i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + str[i];
            }

            return hash;
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        static public Int64 DEKHash(String str)
        {
            Int64 hash = str.Length;

            for (Int32 i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                hash = ((hash << 5) ^ (hash >> 27)) ^ str[i];
            }

            return hash;
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        static public Int64 BPHash(String str)
        {
            Int64 hash = 0;

            for (Int32 i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                hash = hash << 7 ^ str[i];
            }

            return hash;
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        static public Int64 FNVHash(String str)
        {
            Int64 fnv_prime = 0x811C9DC5;
            Int64 hash = 0;

            for (Int32 i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                hash *= fnv_prime;
                hash ^= str[i];
            }

            return hash;
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        static public Int64 APHash(String str)
        {
            Int64 hash = 0xAAAAAAAA;

            for (Int32 i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                if ((i & 1) == 0)
                {
                    hash ^= ((hash << 7) ^ str[i] * (hash >> 3));
                }
                else
                {
                    hash ^= (~((hash << 11) + str[i] ^ (hash >> 5)));
                }
            }

            return hash;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You **could** implement `GetHashCode` by truncating an SHA hash.  But you probably shouldn't.

The purpose of `GetHashCode` is to allow objects to be inserted into [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).  The purpose of hash tables is to optimize searches: On average, finding a key in a hash table requires only O(1) time, compared to O(log n) for a tree, or O(n) for an unsorted list.

You do want your `GetHashCode` method to minimize collisions in order to prevent your hash table lookups from degenerating to O(n) time.  But you also want them to be fast, because the whole point of hash tables is optimization.  If your hash code takes a long time to compute, you might as well have just stored your data in a `List`.

Cryptographic hashes are slow.  They're typically *designed* that way in order to discourage brute force attacks.  This makes them unsuitable for use with `GetHashCode`.

So, how *should* you implement `GetHashCode`?  A simple, frequently-used approach is just to XOR together all the member variables that get used in your `Equals` function.

```
struct Complex
{
    double real;
    double imag;

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return real.GetHashCode() ^ imag.GetHashCode();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Another simple approach, good for array-like objects, is a [polynomial hash function](http://sunilsavanur.wordpress.com/2012/08/14/polynomial-hash-function-for-dictionary-words/).

```
class MyClass
{
    int[] data;

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int result = 0;

        foreach (int n in data)
        {
            result = result * 41 + n;
        }

        return result;
    }

    // ...
}
```

If you class contains a large amount of data to hash, you might want to save the hash code in a member variable and precompute it during construction, so that `GetHashCode()` can then just use that variable.

Comment: The problem with XORing is that if `real` and `image` are the same, you're always going to get 0 as a result.

Comment: @svick Wow, this didn't occur to me when I was looking through the BCL implementations of `GetHashCode()`.  `new Point(x, x).GetHashCode()` gives 0 for any value of `x`

Answer (score 2):

Eric Lippert has created a [great blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx) on how to properly implement a GetHashCode() method. You need to remember that the purpose of GetHashCode() is to put objects into a hash table. Using it for this purpose means that you'll more then likely want to iterate through it or sort it some time in the future. If you are using crypto functions to do this, your iteration or sorting procedure will run very slow. Crypto functions are designed to secure data, not to uniquely identify them. Read through Eric Lippert's blog post. It will help you out

Answer (score 0):

The shorter the width of the hash value, the more likely you are to get collisions.  Since `Int32` stores a maximum of 4294967296 different values you'll need to consider whether this will hold a unique enough value for your purposes - which will depend if this is for security or identity checking.

I'm interested in why you want to override `GetHashCode()`, does the value have to fit into 32bits?  If so why?

Comment: I override Equals(Object obj) in all of my classes, and I want to override GetHashCode() because it throws warning for all of them.  If you override Equals(), the compiler wants you to override GetHashCode() as well, and I would like to do that correctly.

Comment: Why do you override `GetHashCode()` and even more intriguing why are you overriding `Equals()`.  I'd like to know your problem to formulate a better solution.

Comment: I am override Equals() because I want to compare my objects according to my specifications, not the default implementation.

Comment: I didn't answer your other question: GetHashCode() returns a 32-bit Integer, so I need to fit that hash into that, however it is implemented.  I can't return a SHA hash or anything like that because they are way more bits.

Comment: “which will depend if this is for security or identity checking.” You should **never ever** use `GetHashCode()` for that, no matter if 32 bits are enough for you or not.

Comment: @CharlesPerniciaroIII: You are correct that bit count alone make it difficult to use a crypto hash as GetHashCode. But more generally, crypto hashes and GetHashCode are trying to solve *completely different problems*; the characteristics of a good crypto hash are often the *opposite* of a good hash table balancer. Balancing a hash table and signing a document have almost nothing in common; that both operations involve computing a "hash" is unfortunate.